# Is it possible for a column to become a hyperlink using google charts API?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, google-visualization

I am using Visualr http://googlevisualr.herokuapp.com/ with Rails and having a good amount of success creating dynamic charts. However, I am wondering if it's possible to allow the user to click on the column in a 'column chart' and be linked to a page? I am happy to know the java version if you aren't familiar with visualr.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Charts (whether you access them directly or via a wrapper gem like Visualr) are simple images, so the straight answer is "No", at least not without doing some work of your own.  In order to achieve this you would need to place your own transparent clickable links (or divs or whatever) over the image, in the right place, to correspond to the columns that google generate in the image.

I'd imagine this would be tricky and error prone - it might actually be easier for you to just generate the columns yourself in html and css, using the data you would previously have sent to google to set the height (in %) of the columns.  Then, each column would be a seperate html element and could link to whatever you want.

So, more control = more work.  As usual :)

Answer (score 3):

### It now is available!

There has recently been an update on this issue. Therefore I want to update this SO Q&A.

#### Resources:

[Google Visualr Github Pull Request #39](https://github.com/winston/google_visualr/pull/39)
[Google Visualr Github Issue #36](https://github.com/winston/google_visualr/issues/36#issuecomment-9880256)

#### Code example

*xxx_controller.rb*

```
@table = GoogleVisualr::Interactive::ColumnChart.new(g, options_g)
@table.add_listener("select", "function(e) {
                                 EventHandler(e, chart, data_table)
                               }")
```

And then in a JS file e.g. *app/assets/javascripts/application.js*:

```js
function EventHandler(e, chart, data) {
var selection = chart.getSelection();
    if (selection.length > 0) {
        var row = selection[0].row;
        var department = data.getValue(row, 0);
        alert(department + " | " + row)
    }
}
```